# Understanding UML of DoFactory Design Pattern - Decorator

Tags: design-patterns, uml, decorator, aggregation

I am trying to understand UML diagram describing Decorator Pattern at link below

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

I don't understand why there is a "Aggregation" relation between Decorator and Component.

I believe it should be composition as Decorator cannot exist without the base component.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but another perspective: http://lispy.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/why-uml-fails-to-add-value-to-the-design-and-development-process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Composition is stronger that aggregation, it usually means that the object takes ownership of its components. This is not the case in this situation because a decorator doesn't own a decorated object. Moreover you could remove the decorator without a need to remove the decorated object as well.

In practice the line between aggregation and composition can be blurry and often it doesn't make much difference whether you choose one or the other, especially if you treat you diagrams as sketches.

Comment: Thanks Adam. It makes lot of sense now. Just revisited the definition of Composition and aggregation on wiki. Found this ex. "A University can be seen as a composition of departments, whereas departments have an aggregation of professors. In addition, a Professor could work in more than one department, but a department could not be part of more than one university."

Answer (score 2):

Basically because you can have multiple decorators on the component. From wikipedia on [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation):

> #### Differences between Composition and
>   Aggregation
>
> The whole of a composition must have a
>   multiplicity of 0..1 or 1, indicating
>   that a part must be for only one
>   whole. The whole of an aggregation may
>   have any multiplicity.

also

> Composition usually has a strong life
>   cycle dependency between instances of
>   the container class and instances of
>   the contained class(es): If the
>   container is destroyed, normally every
>   instance that it contains is destroyed
>   as well.

note the use of the word 'usually'.

Take a look at the [example decorator diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), also at wikipedia for a clearer example of why this is the case.